# What is the nature of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the nature of the next series (convergent or divergent) and how is it solved?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{ln(n)}, a > 0$

I can't identify a convergence criterion that works (comparison criterion, D'Alambert criterion, Cauchy criterion, Raabe-Duhamel criterion).

Comment: Recall $a^{\log n}=n^{\log a}$.